# Scala, interesting Puzzle with Implicits

Tags: scala, implicit

here is an interesting puzzle that I can not solve for a few days.

A class takes a function and gives out a string. Main thing is that it puts parentheses when a priority of an argument becomes negative. The goal is to find such a relationship of value, literal and operation, that the parentheses will be at initial place

Known is that:

literal * variable is e.g 2X and not 2 * X

Priority of X (or any other variable) is 5

Priority of 42 (e.g 42.lit or 4.lit * 2.lit which one is unknown) is 4

Priority of X * Y * 2 is 3

Priority of -X * Y * 3 is 1

```
    object Main {
    
      trait Expr[T] {
        def literalInt(value: Int): T
        def variable(name: String): T
        def times(x: T, y: T): T
        def plus(x: T, y: T): T
        def minus(x: T, y: T): T = plus(x, negate(y))
        def negate(x: T): T = times(x, literalInt(-1))
      }
    
      object exprSyntax {
        def literalInt[T](value: Int)(implicit expr: Expr[T]): T = expr.literalInt(value)
        def X[T](implicit expr: Expr[T]): T = expr.variable("x")
        def Y[T](implicit expr: Expr[T]): T = expr.variable("y")
        def Z[T](implicit expr: Expr[T]): T = expr.variable("z")
    
        implicit class IntToExpr[T](x: Int)(implicit expr: Expr[T]) {
          def lit: T = expr.literalInt(x)
        }
    
        implicit class NumOps[T](val x: T) extends AnyVal {
          def +(y: T)(implicit expr: Expr[T]): T = expr.plus(x, y)
          def -(y: T)(implicit expr: Expr[T]): T = expr.minus(x, y)
          def *(y: T)(implicit expr: Expr[T]): T = expr.times(x, y)
          def unary_-(implicit expr: Expr[T]): T = expr.negate(x)
        }
      }
    
      final case class Print(s: String, priority: Int, isLit: Boolean = false) {
        def print(outer: Int = 0) = if (outer <= priority) s else s"($s)"
      }

// interesting starts from here
    
        object Expr {
          implicit val stringOrderExpr: Expr[Print] = new Expr[Print] {
            override def literalInt(value: Int): Print = Print(value.toString, priority = ???, isLit = true)
            override def variable(name: String): Print = Print(name.toUpperCase, priority = ???)
            override def times(x: Print, y: Print): Print = {
              if (x.isLit){
                val print = Print(s"${x.s}${y.s}", priority = ???).print()
                Print(print, priority = ???)
              }
              else {
                val print = Print(s"${x.s}*${y.s}", priority = ???).print()
                Print(print, priority = ???)
              }
            }
            override def plus(x: Print, y: Print): Print  = {
              val print = Print(s"${x.s}+${y.s}".toUpperCase, priority = ???).print()
              Print(print, y.priority - x.priority)
            }
    
            override def minus(x: Print, y: Print): Print = {
              val print = Print(s"${x.s}-${y.s}", priority = ???).print()
              Print(print, priority = ???)
            }
            override def negate(x: Print): Print = {
              val print = Print(s"-${x.s}", priority = ???).print()
              Print(print, priority = ???)
            }
          }
      }
    
    
      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        import Main.exprSyntax._
        def function[T: Main.Expr]: T = X * X + 2.lit * (Y + Z * X * 2.lit) - 7.lit * Z + 4.lit
        println(function[Main.Print].priority) // X*X+2(Y+Z*X*2)-7Z+4
      }
    }
```

Comment: Known parts are about strings that come out

Comment: Your problem could be avoided altogether if your `Print` would be just an ADT preserving order and type of operations and evaluated to `String` only when the whole result is built.

Comment: Can't change anything in Print. Only object Expr is changeable

Comment: `Expr[T]` is parametric. You can pretty much create `LazyPrint` that is just a plain ADT, work with `Exprl[LazyPrint]` and interpret `LazyPrint` into `Print`.

Comment: Thank you, sounds like some mindblowing level of Scala usage to me. Need to google how to use such a solution)))

Comment: Not really, you just store each operation in the data (`sealed trait LazyPrint; case class LiterateInt(value: Int) extends LazyPrint; case class Times(a: LazyPrint, b: LazyPrint) extends LazyPrint`) and once you build the whole expression you use pattern patching on it. This way you could e.g. rewrite `lazyPrint match { case Times(LiteralInt(a), LiteralInt(b)) => LiteralInt(a * b); case _ => not a special case] }`